# System.IO.File ExtractFromFile method equivalent?

Tags: .net, file-io, vbscript, qtp

Note: this is not my code. It can be found [here](https://sumeetkushwah.com/2017/03/)

```
Public Function UnZipFile(ByVal SourceFilePath, ByVal TargetExtractFolderName)
    Dim OZipObject
    Set OFile = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.IO.File","System")
    If OFile.Exists(SourceFilePath) Then
        Set OZipObject = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.IO.Compression.ZipFile", "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")
        OZipObject.ExtractToDirectory SourceFilePath, TargetExtractFolderName
    End If
End Function
```

All this does is extract zip files when source path and destination is provided. The problem is that an error is encountered when files already exist, so I just want to overwrite them.

Note that the code uses `ExtractToDirectory` which does not overwrite, so
I tried to use the `ExtractToFile` (which does overwrite) instead this way:

```
Call OZipObject.ExtractToFile(TargetExtractFolderName, True)
```

and I get the error

> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'OZipObject.ExtractToFile'

`ExtractToFile` is not a method of the .NET `System.IO.File` object. I couldn't find anything I needed in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) either.

Is there a method by a different name that does this? Or if there is another way in which I can remain using the `DotNetFactory` object and carry out overwriting duplicates in zip extraction, please let me know.

Comment: What you're using is the [**`ZipFile` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) (not the `File` class), but AFAIK it should overwrite duplicates. What exactly do you expect it to overwrite and how can you tell it doesn't?

Comment: Also, how can you say that the `ExtractToFile` method _**does**_ overwrite when it doesn't exist? -- You extract the zip contents to a directory. Because there can be multiple entries in a zip-file you cannot extract it to a single file.

Comment: Please throw this away.  Add a reference to System.IO.Compression instead.

Comment: @HansPassant. I took your advice, threw this away and used System.IO.Compression instead and it works like a charm. Thanks